# Grammar correction and auxiliary verb

Tags: grammar, singular-vs-plural

> 1. most of the employees
> 2. most of the employee

Which one is right? If *"most of the employee"* is right then which auxiliary verb I have to use, *"is"* / *"are"*?

Answer (score 1):

*Most of the employees* is correct, I believe, because if we are talking about some company, it usually has at least a few employees. And so, most of them can do something. As it's about more than 1 person, the plural form of the noun shall be used. For example:

```
Most of the employees agreed to follow the new rules.
```

*Most of the employee* sounds weird just the way we see it here. You can say, for example, "most of me" in some context. See the lyrics of Mandy Moor's [Most of Me](https://www.vagalume.com.br/mandy-moore/most-of-me.html). And so theoretically we can say "most of the employee" but now I can't come up with any natural situation to give a good example.